# wp_signon returns user, in popup window, but the user is not logged in

Tags: plugins, login

I am creating a login, that pops up a window, takes in credentials and closes when successfully logged in. The code is for a plugin.

I have read and tried everything in [user-is-not-logged-in](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/wp-signon-returns-user-but-the-user-is-not-logged-in) and in [authenticate-user-guidance](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115498/wp-signon-does-not-authenticate-user-guidance-needed). The users appears to be logged in, in the pop-up window. However in the main window, the no user is logged in.

```
    // $user_name and $user_pass are from the form
    $creds = array(
        'user_login'    => $user_name,
        'user_password' => $user_pass,
        'remember'      => true
    );

    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) echo $user->get_error_message();
    else {
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
        do_action( 'wp_login', $user_name);
        if (!session_id()) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $secret->access_token;
            $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $secret->refresh_token;
        }
        //once main window has this user logged, refresh it and close popup
        //print '<script>window.opener.location.reload();window.close();</script>';
        print "$user->user_login : $user->display_name : $user->user_email";
        print (is_user_logged_in())? 'IS LOGGED ALL IN' : 'DOES NOT WORK AT ALL';
    }
```

This outputs **IS LOGGED ALL IN** in the popup window (along with the user info).

What am I missing?

Comment: I have moved this section of the code to the main window. Now it mimics the linked questions. Still, is_user_logged_in() shows true, but trying to access user profile redirects me to login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many things, I tried to redirect after authenticating. However I kept getting the error "*Cannot modify header information - headers already sent*".

I read on [the solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179070/wp-redirect-headers-already-sent) and moved the entire function to this location and it worked.